# Color de fondo en header Jqgrid

Tags: javascript, css, jqgrid

estoy intentando colocar el fondo para los **colNames** de Jqgrid deseo algo asi:

[image: resultado deseado]

esto lo obtengo colocando directamente en el Javascript lo siguiente:

```
 colNames:['', '<span class="badge bg-green">Orden N°</span>','Proveedor'....
```

La idea es usar css para poder tener el mismo efecto.
tambien he probado lo siguiente:

```
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-labels th.ui-th-column {
    background-color: orange;
    background-image: none
}
```

y el resultado es :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

que es totalmente diferente a lo que deseo quiza por donde comenzar o una idea gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dale un bordee-radius a los thead de tu tabla para que quede como quieres.

Ejemplo:

```
.nombre-clase { 
      border-radius: 50px;
}
```

Otra opciones es buscar los estilos que generan las clases **badge bg-green** y copiarlas donde tú quieres que se vea igual.